# SQL Server Management Studio есть проблемка

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня задание сделать 2е таблицы с определенными значениями как на фото, после "запросами вытащить списки должностей с количеством сотрудников, занимающих эти должности" в принципе у меня получилось, но названия профессий остаются как цифры можно это как изменить или вызвать имена профессий с другой таблицы?

[image: Тут таблицы связал]

[image: Первая таблица Prof должны быть переменные int]

[image: Вторая таблица]

[image: То что получилось]

Comment: Меньше картинок, больше кода. Лучше бы вы привели sql-код создания таблиц.

Comment: Я без кода делал таблицы =\

Comment: Правый клик по таблице... С картинками: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11564292/5045688

Comment: У меня на русском языке программа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать объединение двух таблиц:

```
select u.[ID], [Name], p.[Prof]
from [Users] u
join [Prof] p
on u.Prof = p.ID
```

Здесь ID и Name берутся из таблицы Users, а Prof - из таблицы Prof.

Кстати, название для колонки с название профессии неудачное. Я бы использовал Name.